# how to use dynamic css in jsp file base on param value

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp

I have a jsp file ,like this :

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       var type=<bean:write name="class" property="type" />  
     </script> 

     <style type="text/css">
        .td-type1
        {
            width: 10mm;
        }
        .td-type2
        {
            width: 20mm;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-type1">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: How to change css dynamically base on type value?
For example, if type equal 2, then the css class of td-type2 should be used for td tag.
should I use .properties file to save all config or multi css files or ...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can append the request attribute's value to the `class` attribute in the JSP :

```
<td class="td-type<%=type%>">
```

As a side note, the use of scriptlets (java code in JSP's) is strongly discouraged. Use JSTL and EL instead. In this question you'll find out [Why and how to avoid Java Code in JSP files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/851811).

```
<td class="td-type${type}">
```

Or, if you wanted to implement an if-else like construct, for instance :

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${type eq "2"}">
        <c:set var="varclass" value="td-type2"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="varclass" value="td-type1"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
<td class="${varClass}">
```

Comment: I use struts to get type variable,does it make any difference to ur answer?

Comment: @Mina It's been a long time since I've last used it, but if I remember correctly, you'll have some kind of form bean available as a request attribute. It should be the same, accessing the bean's property in the EL expression.